# Distributing app to closed or internal testing track users of specific Organizations

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-play-internal-testing

I have an android app that I publish to external organizations' app stores using the "Managed Google Play" option in the play console. Before publishing a new version of the app to production, I would like for it to be tested by a select set of users. However, in any of the tracks, I am unable to add the organization email id of the testers. Even if I get their gmail ids, the link / invites aren't showing the app. They get a message saying url not found.

I suspect that its the "Managed Google play" configuration thats blocking the distribution.

Could anyone please help figure this out ?

1. Configured organizations' ids in Managed Google Play screen.
2. Created an internal test track.
3. Added organization email ids of users (didn't work)
4. Added gmail id of users (addition worked)

Even after this, the test version of the app isn't visible to any of the users.